# Get unread email and mark as read in one call using EWS Managed API

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a standard routine to get an unread email from a mail server, mark it as read and then process it. It looks similar to this:

```
var view = new ItemView(1);
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
var findResults = ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);

if (findResults.Items.Any())
{
    EmailMessage emailMsg = findResults.Items.First() as EmailMessage;
    emailMsg.IsRead = true;
    emailMsg.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

    ProcessMail(emailMsg);
}
```

This could be invoked from various processes, so I need to ensure atomicity of "find unread / mark as read" operation. In other words between `Service.FindItems()` and `mail.Update()` the same email could be read twice by different processes and result in duplicated processing.

Now, I don't want to get involved in discussion about storing processed email IDs or whether I should be using multiple processes accessing the same email server.

All I want to find out is if there is a EWS API method which does the two operations in one call? Ideally that would be something like this:

```
var mail = ExchangeService.GetFirstUnreadEmailAndMarkItAsRead()
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Trying to determine the same thing.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any updates / ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. An EWS GetItems call doesn't modify the item.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my PowerShell code that achieves this. I run this in Windows task scheduler using a service account that have impersonation rights.

First I have a function 'Connect-EWS' - most the credit for this to [Automativity.com](https://automativity.com/Using-the-EWS-API-with-Powershell/)

```
function Connect-EWS {
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]
    $DiscoverUrl        
)

# First import the DLL, else none of the EWS classes will be available

Try{
    Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
}
Catch{
    Write-Error "Error importing C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    Write-Error $_.Exception
    Break
}

#Put your exchange version in here
$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1

# Create the ExchangeService object
$ExchangeService = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)

$ExchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 

#Autodiscover didnt work for me, but this is how you do it:
#$ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl($AutoDiscoverUrl, {$true})

$ExchangeService.Url = $DiscoverUrl

# Return the object
return $ExchangeService
}
```

This is then what I setup using the function:

```
Write-Host 'Mark Emails Read'
$ExchangeService = Connect-EWS -DiscoverUrl "https://exchangeserver.test.local/ews/exchange.asmx"

$impersonate = "username01@test.local"
$ExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $impersonate)

$ImpersonatedFolder = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderID([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot, $impersonate)
$folderView - New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(100)
$findFolders = $ExchangeService.FindFolders($ImpersonatedFolder,$folderView)

foreach ($folder in $findFolders)
{
   Write-Host 'Unread Items: ' $folder.UnreadCount ' (' $folder.DisplayName ')'
   $folder.MarkAllItemsAsRead($true)
}
```

The output of this is then a print out of each folder's unread items count - before promptly marking EVERYTHING as read.