# How can I mark as read all emails fetched through EWS in a single update?

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, managed

I followed the EWS Managed API example on MSDN to [find all unread email in my Exchange mailbox account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_getewsma).

I later went through each found item in order to place them in the list I need to return while fetching the body of each message and updating each to `IsRead=true` as follows:

```
Folder.Bind(Service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
    new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
//ItemView limits the results to numOfMails2Fetch items
FindItemsResults<Item> foundItems = Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf,
    new ItemView(numOfMails2Fetch));

if (foundItems.TotalCount > 0)
{
    List<EmailMessage> emailsList = new List<EmailMessage>(foundItems.TotalCount);
    foundItems.Items.ToList().ForEach(item =>
    {
        var iEM = item as EmailMessage;
        emailsList.Add(iEM);
        // update properties
        iEM.IsRead = true;
        iEM.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
    });
    // fetches and assign the bodies of each email
    Service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emailsList,PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
    return emailsList;
} else return null;
```

Is it possible to update all of the found items to `IsRead=true` in a single request instead? I.e. without updating them one by one = better performance and coherent logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. `ExchangeService.UpdateItems` is the method you want to use here. See [How to: Process email messages in batches by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn595098(v=exchg.150).aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried that method but it's giving me an exception. I asked a new question relating to it: [why the batch update is not considering the new items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35205424/1326147). If you'd be so kind to figure out why, I can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone finding this thread now.

note that you may be able to use "MarkAllItemsAsRead()" - [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.markallitemsasread?view=exchange-ews-api)

Also see my other reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824852/22362728

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35527863)