# EWS - This operation can't be performed because one or more items are new or unmodified

Tags: c#, email, exception, exchangewebservices, managed

Relating to a batch update question I asked previously about using a [single update to mark as read all the unread emails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35203239/1326147), I could use `ExchangeService.UpdateItems` according to [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204439/1326147).

So I modified accordingly:

```
Folder.Bind(Service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
    new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

//ItemView limits the results to numOfMails2Fetch items
FindItemsResults<Item> foundItems = Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf,
    new ItemView(numOfMails2Fetch));

if (foundItems.TotalCount > 0)
{
    List<EmailMessage> emailsList = new List<EmailMessage>(foundItems.TotalCount);

    foundItems.Items.ToList().ForEach(item =>
    {
        var iEM = item as EmailMessage;
        // update properties BEFORE ADDING
        iEM.IsRead = true;

        //DO NOT UPDATE INSIDE THE LOOP,I.E. DO NOT USE:
        //iEM.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

        //add the EmailMessage to the list
        emailsList.Add(iEM);
    });

    // fetches the body of each email and assigns it to each EmailMessage
    Service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emailsList,PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    // Batch update all the emails
    ServiceResponseCollection<UpdateItemResponse> response =
      Service.UpdateItems(emailsList,
       WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, 
       MessageDisposition.SaveOnly, null);
    // ABOVE LINE CAUSES EXCEPTION
    return emailsList;
}
```

Notice that I pulled up the `IsRead` attribution, placed it before adding the item to the list. The exception is the following:

> This operation can't be performed because one or more items are new or unmodified

From [MSDN's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn595098%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_updateewsma) it seems setting `IsRead` to true should be enough, so why are the items not being considered for the batch update?

Comment: FYI it is crazy hard reading your code Im not surprised you are getting issues as it doesn't even read properly.... just for each over the collection.

Comment: Are you not able to drop the outer loop tho and just have a foreach over the return back from Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf,
    new ItemView(numOfMails2Fetch));

Comment: @Seabizkit There is only one loop, I adjusted the code for improved readability. Jason below identified the problem, it was due to the order of the `LoadPropertiesForItems` and `UpdateItems`, I just placed the load method after (reversed it) and voilá, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first guess it's the `LoadPropertiesForItems` call you make outside the loop. This likely overwrites your changes by loading the values back from the server.

Comment: Thanks again Jason! It was exactly that, I switched the order of those 2 lines and worked as expected. Lol, should have thought of that before, the load is a kind of a reset to the previous status of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the answer... I just wanted to check if you could format it something like so

```
    Folder.Bind(Service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

    var sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

    //ItemView limits the results to numOfMails2Fetch items
    var foundItems = Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, new ItemView(numOfMails2Fetch)).ToList();

    // fetches the body of each email and assigns it to each EmailMessage
    Service.LoadPropertiesForItems(foundItems,PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    //List<EmailMessage> emailsList = new List<EmailMessage>();
    foreach(var item in foundItems)
    {
      var iEM = item as EmailMessage;
      if(iEM != null)
          iEM.IsRead = true;
      //emailsList.Add(iEM);
    }

    // Batch update all the emails
    var response = Service.UpdateItems(foundItems, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, MessageDisposition.SaveOnly, null);

    return foundItems;
}
```